# Fetch data inside an action in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on a project where I must fetch some data inside the actions.

Here is the actions file:

```
import {
  REQUEST_DEFERRED_PAYMENTS,
  SELECT_LINE_ITEM,
} from '../constants/actionTypes';
import { SUCCESS } from '../constants/status';
import { orders } from '../constants/data'; // hard-coded data

export const selectLineItem = (lineItems, total) => {
  return {
    type: SELECT_LINE_ITEM,
    response: {
      lineItems,
      total,
    },
  };
};

export const fetchDeferredPayments = (query) => {
  // TODO: FETCH FROM API
  // hardcoded data

  if (orders) {
    return {
      type: `${REQUEST_DEFERRED_PAYMENTS}_${SUCCESS}`,
      response: orders,
    };
  }
  return {};
};

export const buildQuery = (params) => {
  // TODO:
};
```

at this moment, the data is hard-coded and it is taken from `/constants/data` and stored into `orders`.

I was wondering if it's possible to to replace the use of hard-coded data inside `fetchDeferredPayments`.

The curl looks like this:

```
curl --location --request GET 'tfcommerce-api-eks.cloudqa.thermofisher.net/api/store/orders/deferred-payments/search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'userId: 915918' \
--header 'countryCode: kr' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic dGZkZWZlcnJlZHBheW1lbnRzOnRoZXJtb2Zpc2hlXXX=' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=D330BF758C8F9E916031DC51CD25FXXX' \
--data-raw '{
"searchQueryParams": {
"orderType": "tc",
"dateFrom": "2019-11-20",
"dateTo": "2020-11-25"
},
"requestOptions": {
"sortOrder": "asc",
"sortProperty": "orderDate"
}
}'
```

I replaced the last characters from Authorization and Cookie headers from security reasons.

Comment: What is the problem, you can change in fetchDeferredPayments

Comment: @RahulSharma I don't know how to build the fetch method

Comment: Redux action creators are meant to be pure functions that return a plain object with at least a `type` property. To write action creators that have async code you need a Redux middleware like Redux Thunks: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: @ShriharshaKL do you think it is the only solution? Isn't it possible without redux-thunk?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `redux-thunk` to manually trigger actions inside action by `dispatch` and return an action because you can not return anything inside `promise.then(() => {})`

Alternative can be `redux-promise`, it will resolve the promise for you.

Below is thunk example

Typically, you should structure like this

```
export const fetchDeferredPayments = (query) => {
  // TODO: FETCH FROM API
  // hardcoded data
  
  // When the API request start, dispatch START action, for triggering loading 
  // spinner or something like this on the application state
  dispatch(callAPIStart());

  callAPI()
    .then(orders => dispatch(callAPISuccess(orders)))      
    .catch(error => dispatch(callAPIFailed))
};

const callAPISuccess = (orders) => ({ type: CALL_API_SUCCESS, payload: orders })
```

Inside reducers switch case:

```
case CALL_API_SUCCESS: return {...state, orders: action.payload}
```

The code above is only the idea because I do not have your full code. Ask any question if you have, you're welcome.

Comment: my question is where should be added the headers part

Comment: So I think you should edit your post if you do not want to get many down votes. For config the headers, it based on your lib used to call HTTP, `axios` or `fetch` has its own way to config headers.